# UnsatisfiedDependencyException using @DataJpaTest with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using SpringBoot and I have a DataJpaTest, but when I run the Test class, I get this StackTrace:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in br.com.mobtrack.api.MobTrackApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'restTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
```

I think this happens because I have a `RestTemplate` bean inside my `Application` class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

This is my Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class CityRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    private City city;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        city = new City();
        city.setName("New York");
        city.setImage("http://www.mockimage.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void findByNameShouldReturnCity() throws Exception {
        this.entityManager.persist(city);
        Optional<City> hasCity = this.cityRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase("New York");
        city = hasCity.get();
        assertThat(city.getId()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(city.getName()).isEqualTo("New York");
        assertThat(city.getImage()).isEqualTo("http://www.mockimage.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void findByNameStartingWithShouldReturnCity() throws Exception {
        this.entityManager.persist(city);
        Optional<City> hasCity = this.cityRepository.findByNameStartingWithIgnoreCase("New");
        city = hasCity.get();
        assertThat(city.getId()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(city.getName()).isEqualTo("New York");
        assertThat(city.getImage()).isEqualTo("http://www.mockimage.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void findByNameWhenNoCityShouldReturnFalse() throws Exception {
        this.entityManager.persist(city);
        Optional<City> hasCity = this.cityRepository.findByNameStartingWithIgnoreCase("Ohaio");
        assertThat(hasCity.isPresent()).isFalse();
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome,Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is clearly saying - there is no qualifying bean of type `RestTemplateBuilder` being available for use of `RestTemplate` bean building.

The bean for `RestTempalteBuilder` is injected into context by the spring boot starter for web. There is generally no need to declare a RestTemplateBuilder bean into the context as it is already provided by the spring-boot auto-configuration. If the project is a spring-boot application this will work out of box as intended.

If required, one can customise it by creating a new one in the application configuration.Something like below:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .basicAuthorization("abc", "password");
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

And if no real reason to customise it, you could rather have a simpler bean definition for RestTemplate as below:

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like the other solution as I did want my application to use the spring provided RestTemplateBuilder since it provides some default message converters and other functionality I needed when running my app.

However I found 2 ways to alter my test to get my DataJpaTest's to run, not sure which is best:

Method One - provide a mock RestTemplate in your test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class SomeTest {

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Method Two - add AutoConfigureWebClient annotation so spring will wire the RestTemplateBuilder

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureWebClient
public class SomeTest {
```

With both ways I could keep my existing configured rest template in my application class:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```